# Clojure Value out of range for long

Tags: clojure, long-integer, integer-overflow

I have a simple power function, and I want to do something like this using two large numbers:

```
(def y 19859145917581983573N)
(def p 27829350753993985481N)
(defn power
  [x n]
  (reduce *' (repeat n x))
  )
(power y p)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException Value out of range for long: 27829350753993985481  clojure.lang.RT.longCast (RT.java:1210)
```

Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to do modular exponentiation by any chance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are going to have to find a more efficient method of exponentiation than simple repeated multiplication. You're asking your computer to perform 27 quintillion bigint multiplications! Even if we assume, quite charitably, that you can perform a billion such operations per second, it would take you 900 years to complete this calculation.

But let's suppose you're willing to wait that long. You'll have to perform a few memory upgrades on your computer too: the resulting number would take up (very roughly) as much space on your machine as the entire storage capacity of the Internet (as of 2016 anyway: when you finally finish multiplying, in the year 2900, they will probably have thumb drives this size).

If that's no problem for you either, then you will just have to write a version of `repeat` that uses bigints for counting repetitions instead of a long:

```
(defn repeat' [n x]
  (lazy-seq 
    (when (> n 0N)
      (cons x (repeat' (dec' n) x)))))
```